# Table cell borders get stripped by ckeditor in Internet Explorer when pasted from Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ms-word, ckeditor

I'm having an issue where ckeditor 4.3.1 is removing border styles in Internet Explorer 10 on html tables when pasted from MS Word. Chrome and Firefox work as expected. `border` and `border-(top|right|bottom|left)` styles are explicitly listed in the `allowedContent` config for `table`, `tr`, `th`, and `td` elements.

**Relevant ckeditor config overrides:**

```
$("#textareaElement").ckeditor({
    pasteFromWordRemoveStyles: false,
    pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles: false,
    // allowedContent below is redacted to show only the td element
    allowedContent: 'td{border,border-top,border-right,border-bottom,border-left,background,padding,width,height}'

    // toolbar and toolbarGroups not shown
});
```

When the exact same Word document is pasted into the editor, the resulting HTML is different.

**Sample `td` element after paste, IE:**

```
<td style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 87px; height: 32px;">
    <p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12pt"><span>This is the cell content</span></span></p>
</td>
```

**Sample `td` element after paste, Chrome:**

```
<td style="border-top:none; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; height:32px; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt; width:87px">
    <p align="center" style="text-align:center"><span><span style="font-size:12.0pt">This is the cell content</span></span></p>
</td>
```

The above examples are the same element. None of the `border` styles survive the paste in Internet Explorer, but they work perfect in other browsers. Using IE's dev tools Console tab to drill down into the `filter.allowedContent` object for the `CKEDITOR.editor` instance, I have verified that all the styles are correctly loaded in during initialization and are listed as allowed for `td` elements, but they end up getting stripped anyway.

I haven't had any luck from browsing the ckeditor api docs, or google, or other SO answers.

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious. Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any known workarounds?